# Converting a .string to .quad in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, att

I just started learning assembly language and we got a homework assignment where the objective of the assignment is to write a program that will convert signed integers expressed as character strings into 2’s complement encodings.

So I thought one thing we need to do is when we enter a string like "10" we will need to break it up into like "1" and "0" and then do the conversion 2’s complement encodings(let me know if you think this is a correct approach).

So I made this small program - just to extract the "1" of the "10".

Here are some comments for the code where the numbers are in the code

1. Moves the character code of "1" (0x31) into register `rax`.
   That is `R[rax] <- M[R[rbx]+0] = M[asc] = 0x31`.
2. Moves the character code of "0" (0x30) into register `rcx`.
   That is `R[rcx] <- M[R[rbx]+1] = M[asc+1] = 0x30`.
3. Moves the character code of "1" (0x31) into `answ`. Also, I'm not really sure what `%al` does, it was recommended by my teacher.

Then in gdb I put a break on the `ret` statement like `break *main+18`
and then I enter `x/xg $answ`

After that I get an error

> value can't be converted to an integer

I'm not sure how to fix this. Thanks for the help. The program is:

```
.data 
  asc: .string "10"
  answ: .quad

.text
.globl main

main: 
  mov $asc, %rbx
  mov 0(%rbx), %rax  #1
  mov 1(%rbx), %rcx   #2
  mov %al, 3(%rbx)    #3
  ret
```

Comment: if it makes it easier use a language other than assembly first.  Like C for example or many others.  and no that doesnt mean use strtoul.  but walk the string, come up with the algorithm then once you have the algorithm in a language you are natural at, then simply code that algorithm in assembly language.

Comment: if i dont figure it out soon, then i will do that and post it.

Comment: Please [edit] to improve your question title. As it is now, it's a recitation of your assignment and not a question or problem description. My immediate reaction was to vote to close as a copy/paste of your assignment. Your title should describe the problem you're having or the question you're asking, and should be something that will have meaning to future readers when seen in a search result.

Comment: i changed the tittle, i hope that it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

- `%al` (and `%ar`) are registers.  Here's a good diagram:

  - RAX is the 64-bit value
  - EAX is the 32-bit value
  - AX is the lower 16-bits
  - AL is the lower 8 bits
  - AH is the bits 8 through 15 (zero-based)
- The ASCII character for "0" is `0x30`.  The ASCII character for "1" is `0x31`.  So your "string of 1s and 0s will look something like  `0x30303130...`
- The reason `x/xg $answ` gives an error is that it's a gdb syntax error.  Here's a good "cheat sheet":

  - http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~cpatel2/links/310/nasm/gdb_help.shtml

ALSO:

- "Programming from the Ground Up", by Jonathan Barlett, is a *wonderful* resource.  And it's completely free - he posted the entire text on-line:

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/

Comment: are you saying that "x/xg $answ" is my only mistake

Comment: No, I was just answering the specific questions.  Your main problem is still to figure out how to convert a signed string into the corresponding bits.  Positive numbers are easy: you just work a byte at a time, subtract "0x30" and shift the bit into your result. Negative numbers are a bit more challenging: "-1", for example, will have a completely different bit pattern than "1".  SUGGESTION: Get it working for 1 positive digit, 0..9, first.  Please do look at the PGU book, too.

Comment: i havent gotten that far in the assignment yet. i was thinking that i would need to break up each character first and then when i figure that out, i will work on converting them.